# Delphi Can't load package the specified module cannot be found

Tags: delphi, components, advantage-database-server

Delphi 10.3
Windows 10

I am trying to install the TDataSet component for Advantage Database. I have already installed it to my laptop without any trouble. The laptop has the same systems.

On my desktop I get the error Can't load package... the specified module cannot be found.

I have searched for answers for hours. Others with the same problem have solved it with path adjustments. The modules do exist and are on the search path. I even added it to the system environment variable. That was not necessary on the laptop. There is only one .dcp package that is not a regular system file and it compiles to the standard Public\Embarcadero...\dcp directory.

After hours of searching I'm ready to give up. Any new ideas?

The required section contains:

```
adsd103Rio.dcp, //I triple checked the spelling
dcldb.dcp,
designide.dcp,
rtl.dcp,
vcl.dcp
```

Any new ideas?
Gary

Comment: The _specified module_ can as well be some DLL needed by the package.

Comment: Nothing else but a single .pas file is required. The adsd103Rio.dcp only uses .pas files as well and compiles fine. BTW both packages compile fine it is only when I try to install the design Time package that I get the error

Comment: Usually you don't need a DLL when you compile, but perhaps when you load the package. IIRC you need at least the ace32.dll to access ADS.

Comment: Could by I'll check. Thank you.

Comment: I added the directory with the ace32.dll to the Library path as well as the System path. Same results

Comment: The Library path is not used for DLL searching, but the PATH environment variable is.

Answer (score 6):

i had same issue. spent hours on this.
Here is the solution that worked for me:

go to this thread:
[Can't load package %s error while installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726735/cant-load-package-s-error-while-installing-a-package)

Look for answer that starts with this:

Run Process Monitor from http://SysInternals.com and set the filters to intercept only file operations ( toolbar rightmost buttons ) of your Delphi IDE process (check the process name in TaskManager or shortcut properties (it is bds.exe for Delphi XE2), then add the filter similar to Include / Process Name / Ends With / bds.exe ).

Comment: That got me on the track. Uwe Raabe was right as well. Since there is no component for Rio yet there are some hoops to jump through. I missed this step.  Then copy the content of the System32 folder to Windows\System32 (on Win32 systems) or Windows\SysWOW64 (on Win64 systems). Thanks a million!!

Comment: No. Don't modify system directories. That's always the wrong solution. Those are system directories and you just not modify them.

Comment: That sentence was out of context. It is part of a workaround that extracted files intended to be installed into the system folders into it's own sub directory named System32. Those files needed to be copied into the system folder as part on the process.

Comment: I had the same problem.  ProcessMonitor showed the BPL it couldn't find.  It was in the same folder as the package I was installing, but it couldn't find it until I added that folder to the Windows system path variable and restarted Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

> copy all your components in below path:
> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl

This advise has really solved problem on my side!

Comment: This is not a real solution. A BPL should be installable from anywhere. This however solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727833/46207

Answer (score 1):

Run  as a administrator, it works for me.

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Comment: This however solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727833/46207

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. please copy all your components in below path:
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\Bpl

Comment: This is not a real solution. A BPL should be installable from anywhere. This however solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727833/46207

Answer (score 0):

The .bpl files for Designtime package and Runtime package must be in the same folder (usually in \Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\xx.x\Bpl).

Comment: Actually no: The runtime package must be in the same folder or in the Windows search path